# Keeping scroll position after a postback

Tags: javascript

I have a screen, with a table records which has buttons in each line.
Each button executes an action and returns to the same screen.
The problem is the page goes back to top, and i need it to load where people clicked, so it is more user friendly. 
I was thinking in somehow create an anchor when someone clicks and then, when loading the page, just load it on the previous anchor.
Any suggestions?

```
<td align=\"center\" ".$proceed_bg."> 
 <select>
  <option value=\"1\" ".$proceed." onClick=\"window.location='index.php?pages=jobsheet&jobsheet_id3=".$row->jobshee‌​t_refno."&product_status=1&pageNum=".$pageNum." ' ;\">Proceed</option> 
  <option value=\"2\" ".$prod_done." onClick=\"window.location='index.php?pages=jobsheet&jobsheet_id3=".$row->jobshee‌​t_refno."&product_status=2&pageNum=".$pageNum."';\">Done</option>
 </select>
</td>
```

Comment: What kind of actions do the buttons execute? Posting your code would allow for more detailed suggestions.

Comment: It's seems you forget to call `preventDefault` function.

Comment: @user3106784 edit your question and update it like what i did in your code by clicking on the `edit` link from `share|edit|flag` shown just below your question.

Comment: @Tony, can explain more detail how it could be done with preventDefault. Thanks

Comment: You should use ajax to do what you want. Your current approach is quite weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.crondesign.com/2009/09/scrollfix-remember-scroll-position-when.html

Hi everyone, i have found my answer through this website.